# Windows Subsytem Linux with MobaXterm: How configure the SFTP pan

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-tunnel, mobaxterm

I have install the Windows Subsystem Linux on my Windows Computer and install Ubuntu on it.

To have a better view of the system, i use MobaXterm as client for the WSL, but i can't have the SFTP pan on it.
I want to upload some files or programs from my Windows PC into the WSL but i don't know how to do it.
I read somewhere that I need to configure a SSH tunnel between my Windows PC and the WSL to allow the drag and drop SFTP pan.

Someone can explain me how to do it ? (I'm new in the computer fields).

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**
From the question, I assume, that you are already able to connect to the WSL via MobaXterm. But, you are missing the file browser in the left pane. In this case, when you connect, you see something like that on the top:

```
| ⮞ Linux distribution: Ubuntu-22.04                                  │
│ ⮞ Windows drives are mounted into /mnt path (by default)             │
│ ⮞ Your DISPLAY is set to <YourLocalIpAdress>                         |
```

**Solution**
In such a case, the wrong "run method" is used.

In the settings of the respective sessions:

- go to "WSL"
- change the "run method" to "localhost connection". It might have been set to a wrong one or to "Autodetection" before.

Now connect with the updated session settings and MobaXterm should show the SFTP pane. Note also that it now shows the following connection information at the top:

```
│ ⮞ Linux distribution: Ubuntu-22.04                                  │
│ ⮞ Windows drives are mounted into /mnt path (by default)             │
│ ⮞ WSL DISPLAY is automatically redirected to Windows desktop         │
│ ⮞ WSL filesystem is accessible in the sidebar browser                │
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Even with run method = "localhost connection" I do not get an SFTP pane...